# Facebook Like Box not showing faces

Tags: facebook, facebook-likebox

I'm trying to implement facebook like box on my web page.I grab the code from the facebook page.This is the code :

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FQue-Quieres%2F125395724210421&amp;width=350&amp;height=258&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;border_color=%23fff&amp;stream=false&amp;header=false" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:350px; height:258px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

The page has more than 100 Likes (fans) but in the box it display just 4 users or 5 sometimes.
When I change the height to 800px I'm able to see more faces (18) but the box will look like hell...the height is too high.
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

If you want the answer of the above question just go to the link below and read the full article. I think your problem will be solved.

http://hottest-tips-and-tricks.blogspot.com/2012/03/if-your-facebook-like-box-not-showing.html#more.